# getting 'Assertion failed' while running the code 'gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)'

Tags: face-detection, face-recognition, opencv, python

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('E:/DATA 
    ANALYTICS/IMARTICUS/PGA06/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('E:/DATA ANALYTICS/IMARTICUS/PGA06/haarcascade_eye.xml')
    img = cv2.imread("E:\\DATA ANALYTICS\\IMARTIC`US\\PGA06\\images\\chiru(1).jpeg")
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

getting the following error while running the code
error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

How i get resolve the issue